# Rubymotion isn't showing error backtrace?

Tags: rubymotion

I'm transposing an XCode iOS application over to Rubymotion and, in doing so, I'm running into a lot of errors.

The problem is, when I run rake to build the app I never see any error messages or backtrace. The app just crashes with no feedback.

Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Here's my rake config incase it helps shed some light

```
build_dir              : "./build"
codesign_certificate   : "iPhone Developer: Bodacious (ABCXXX)"
delegate_class         : "AppDelegate"
deployment_target      : "5.1"
device_family          : :iphone
entitlements           : {}
files                  : [ # ... array of file names ]
fonts                  : []
frameworks             : ["UIKit", "Foundation", "CoreGraphics", "CoreLocation", "MapKit", "SystemConfiguration"]
icons                  : ["Default.png", "icons/logo.png", "icons/logo@2x.png"]
identifier             : "com.bodacious.MyApp"
interface_orientations : [:portrait]
libs                   : ["/usr/lib/libz.dylib"]
name                   : "My App"
pods                   : # long array of data
prerendered_icon       : false
provisioning_profile   : "/Users/Bodacious/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/MyHex.mobileprovision"
resources_dir          : "./resources"
sdk_version            : "5.1"
seed_id                : "ABC123"
specs_dir              : "./spec"
testflight             : {:sdk=>"vendor/TestFlight", :api_token=>"XXX", :team_token=>"XXX", :distribution_lists=>nil}
version                : "0.21.0"
xcode_dir              : "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone else stumbled across this in the future, something to try is to turn on the debugger:

```
rake debug=1
```

This will suspend the crash so you can examine (in the REPL) your current state to try and find out what's happening.

Beyond that, I've found it's helpful to comment out large portions of my app and gradually re-enable them until I narrow the bug down to a particular line. Yes, old-school debugging. :)